# Difference between {{did-update}} and <div {{did-update}}> in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

When I use did-update without wrapping using `<div>`, the action using in did-update fall into infinite loop. After wrapping with `<div>`, the problem has solved.

Here's an example code: (`current` is service which shows the current status)

**Does not work:**
(when `this.current.locationId` changed, `this.updateStates` be executed infinitly)

```
{{did-update this.updateStates this.current.locationId}}
```

**Does work:**

```
<div {{did-update this.updateStates this.current.locationId}}>
</div>
```

> **JS file:**
>
> ```
> @tracked property;
>
> @action
> updateStates() {
>   //do something with `this.current.locationId`
>   //change value of `property`
>   //so template re-render cause of `property` changed
>   ...
> }
> ```

I guess the problem happens because of the tracking frame. But I can not exactly see why that kind of problem is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which addon is bringing in `{{did-update}}`, it looks like it only defines a *modifier*.

When using the *globals resolver* (where you don't need to import anything), the syntax matters more than the name of the thing you're typing.

So,
`{{did-update}}` in a template is a *helper*. This will be looked up in app / addon's `helpers` directories.
`<div {{did-update}}>` is a *modifier*. This will be looked up in app / addon's `modifiers` directories.

I made this little explainer for how to read the syntax:

```
<div {{this.modifierName a b=(this.helperName c)}}>
{{!--  │                 │ │  │               └─── positional argument
       │                 │ │  └─── helper
       │                 │ └─── named argument key
       │                 └─── positional argument
       └─── modifier --}}
  {{yield to="default"}}
{{!--  │  │   └─── value
       │  └─── named argument key
       └─── helper --}}
</div>

<div {{@modifierName a b=(@helperName c)}}>
{{!--  │             │ │  │           └─── positional argument
       │             │ │  └─── helper
       │             │ └─── named argument key
       │             └─── positional argument
       └─── modifier --}}
  {{yield to="default"}}
{{!--  │  │   └─── value
       │  └─── named argument key
       └─── helper --}}
</div>
```

From: https://cheatsheet.glimmer.nullvoxpopuli.com/docs/templates

---

There is a slight difference when you a local value. For example:

```
class Demo extends Component {
  foo = () => {};
}
```

using this function, `foo`, we can use it the following ways

```
{{this.foo}} renders, but is a function, so it doesn't render nicely
{{ (this.foo) }} invokes the function and renders the output, or nothing if undefined

<div {{this.foo}}></div> errors, because the function, foo, is not a modifier
<div {{ (this.foo) }}></div> invokes foo, because it is a function / helper, returns undefined, which is now in "modifier space", undefined modifiers are no-ops, and does nothing. This is useful for when you want to do conditional modifiers
<div {{ (if this.someCondition this.myModifier}}) }}></div> this will collapse down to (if some condition is true):
<div {{this.myModifier}}></div>

<this.foo /> errors, because the function, foo, does not have an associated component manager / foo is not a component.
```

Comment: It definitely helped me. But I don't understand why it falls into an infinite loop yet. Maybe is it the difference between a helper and a modifier? Additionally, `store.query` is used in the `updateStates` function.

Comment: ah sorry -- I didn't answer the full question! (only like.. 20% of it) -- a secret implementation detail of the did-update modifier is that it uses a secret private api that runs the callback in an `untrack` callback -- which is probably what is keeping you from the infinite loop -- changes to tracked data within `untrack` are not detected by the rest of your app -- the desire for untrack is usually due some less-than-ideal data-flow designs, and lead to the need of refactoring.

Comment: So do you mean the data-flow design of our app is wrong?

Comment: Generally when effects come in to play, data-flow could use re-working -- this goes for many ecosystems -- even React, where useEffect usage is rampant -- most of things can be replaced by derived data (getters, or let/const assigning).

My *hunch* would be that if updateStates updates some value called "states", we can define "states" to be derived from locationId, and make it a lot simpler.

Comment: If you want to workshop this, hop in the discord, and we can talk through details -- the invite link is here: https://discord.gg/emberjs -- which can be found here: https://emberjs.com/community/